# Using jarjarlinks to include only used classes in a jar

Tags: java, dependency-management

I have an application that makes use of about 20 external jar files.  In order to package everything up into a single file for distribution, I've been unjaring all the externals into a particular directory and then rejaring it all up into one jar.  The end result is about 2MB in size.  I want to use jarjarlinks to cut down the size of the distribution jar, but I can't find any examples on how to do what I want.

Essentially, I want to only take from the external jars, the classes that I am using and discard all the rest.  Can jarjarlinks do that?  If not, is there some other utility that anyone would recommend?

My sources so far:

http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/GettingStarted

http://jonasboner.com/2005/12/09/stay-out-of-jar-hell-with-jar-jar-links.html

http://sixlegs.com/blog/java/dependency-killer.html

Comment: I've made (potentially) some progress.  Looking at the command line wiki, there's a rule called keep, which takes a pattern and treats any classes that fit that pattern as roots.  Any other classes that are not connected via dependencies to those roots are discarded.  This seems to be exactly what I want, however, whenever I run it, the resulting jar is corrupt.  I extracted it, and the manifest file is missing.  I can't see any immediate way to prevent this from happening - there doesn't seem to be a manifest argument or anything to the process directive.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a tool called *autojar*.

Regarding the manifest file, you can add one with the -e option of the jar command once the jar is packaged:

```
jar -uvfe myjar.jar full.name.of.class.with.main.method
```

Comment: That did it.  All told, I shaved about 1MB in size.  Thanks for the tip.